# "Error occurred during the build" on Maven for L2switch from github

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, opendaylight

I have Ubuntu 20.04 in my virtual box with Java 11 and Apache Maven 3.6.3. I downloaded L2switch implementation from GitHub (https://github.com/opendaylight/l2switch). Whenever I import it on eclipse it shows "Error occurred during the build". On build section it shows:

```
Errors occurred during the build. 
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'addresstracker-impl'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'addresstracker-model'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'arphandler-impl'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'features-l2switch'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'hosttracker-impl'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'hosttracker-model'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'loopremover-impl'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'loopremover-model'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'main-impl'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-addresstracker'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-all'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-arphandler'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-hosttracker'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-loopremover'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-packethandler'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-switch'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'odl-l2switch-switch-rest'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'packethandler-impl'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'packethandler-model'.
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
```

And on Importing Maven Projects section shows-

```
An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.createMojoExecutionBuildParicipant(org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade, org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution, org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.IPluginExecutionMetadata)'
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Which version of *Eclipse* is it?

Comment: It is Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)